# Papaja and quarto

Tags: papaja, quarto

Has anyone looked into using papaja with quarto, yet?

I've tried rendering a qmd file with

```
format:
  papaja::apa6_pdf:
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: true
```

in the header, but in seems that the render fails because of invalid YAML.

Comment: You can't use R Markdown format like papaja developed as R format within Quarto. 
So it won't work to just do that in YAML.
Only quarto format can be used after the `format` key, and it would require developing a new custom format for Quarto similar to papaja.

Comment: You can see the set of output formats here: https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/all-formats.html

Comment: If this is urgent, a bare bones manual approach is outlined in [this papaja issue](https://github.com/crsh/papaja/issues/540). We are currently developing a proper template [here](https://github.com/crsh/qapaja/).